# UIDocument update in iCloud is not notified

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I've implemented iCloud sync of a single document. 
The stand is always actual, when the app starts, but changes made in parallel on other device are never (I saw it once, not sure if I didn't dream that time) propagated when the app is running.

I've implemented

```
                _metadataQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
                _metadataQuery.searchScopes = @[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope];
                _metadataQuery.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, fileName];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(metadataQueryDidUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:_metadataQuery];
                [_metadataQuery startQuery];
```

and it's get called, e.g. when I save the document (so principally it works).

And also

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentStateChanged:) name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification object:self];
```

for the subclassed UIDocument.

In Xcode I see some download activities for my app after I do changes on another device... (but it never show any upload activities, even if I see on another device data getting to be actualized)

But corresponding methods don't get called.
If I do cold restart of the App - everything is fine (I get the "new" data).

Any ideas what could be missing?
Note: may be it's somehow relevant - I'm closing the document right after reading, so the document is typically in state "closed"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've reused wrong example, had to use

_metadataQuery.searchScopes = @[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitous**Documents**Scope];